# Git Submodules With Common Clone Directories

Tags: git, git-submodules, llvm-c++-api, lld

I'm working on a project that uses [LLVM](https://llvm.org) and [LLD](https://lld.llvm.org), which are stored in separate remote repositories (https://git.llvm.org/git/llvm, https://git.llvm.org/git/lld). To build LLD, it must be cloned inside of LLVM, where the LLVM build system will detect its presence and generate build targets for it ([documentation](https://lld.llvm.org/getting_started.html)). Precisely:

`LLD_CLONE_DIR = LLVM_CLONE_DIR/tools/lld`

I would like to use git submodules, and invoke `git submodule update --init --recursive` (during CMake configuration).

I've found that git doesn't handle putting one submodule inside another submodule, for instance:

```
[submodule "contrib/llvm/tools/lld"]
    path = contrib/llvm/tools/lld
    url = https://git.llvm.org/git/lld
[submodule "contrib/llvm"]
    path = contrib/llvm
    url = https://git.llvm.org/git/llvm
```

I thought of making my build script construct a symlink, but it's unreliable on some platforms (Windows). How can I structure the directories so that the LLVM build system will be happy, but I can use git submodules to clone both repositories?

**Update**: I've succesfully used CMake's file command to copy the lld sources to the correct location. I'm still interested in a better solution though.

Comment: I do not think that you *must* clone LLD inside the LLVM Folder, in the documentation you linked it says "lld can also be checked out to path/to/llvm-project and built as an external project."